# Taxonomy landing pages

Tags: custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I like to create a landing page for my custom taxonomies. Right now ive created three custom taxonomies

```
/country/[terms]
/person/[terms]
/interrests/[terms]
```

i like to create a listing page for each of the taxonomy, this listing page should list all the [terms] they contain. And link to the normal (`taxonomy-[term].php` `/taxonomy/[term]`) url. What is a proper way to implement this?

First i was thinking something along the lines with [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) and create a custom `taxonomy-list.php` file to include in the action which manually query using a `WP_Query()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see at least 3 ways to do that.

1. Adding a rewrite rule. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API for details:

   ```
   add_rewrite_rule('^(country|person|interest)/?','index.php?tax=$matches[1]','top');
   ```

   then use the `template_redirect` filter to load your template when the `tax`variable is there:

   ```
   if (get_query_var('tax')) {
       # load the template here 
   }
   ```

   You'll also need to add the `tax` query var to the list of filtered vars using the `query_vars` filter.
2. Creating pages using specific template to list the terms
3. Creating pages and use a shortcode to list the terms

Comment: How would you load the template ?\

Comment: well, actually, if the goal is just to load a template the best is to hook template_include instead of template_redirect https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to create three custom files: `taxonomy-country.php`, `taxonomy-person.php` and `taxonomy-interrests.php`.

Pay attention to suffixes of those templates. It has to be the same as in taxonomy registration. For instance if you register your taxonomy like `register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'book' ), $args );`, then your custom template has to have `taxonomy-genre.php` file name.